# Avoid space after iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

This is the code I'm using to play youtube video. I want to decrease the `height` of `iframe`. Here I changed `height` to `80%` from `100%`. So it is giving space between video and sample text. I want to avoid this space. How to do this. Any suggestions please.

```css
.videoWrapper {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
 padding-top: 25px;
 height: 0;
 text-align:center;
 margin-bottom:1%;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoWrapper" id="tmp">
<iframe id="crntplay" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/id?autoplay=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
 some text here
```

**Problem:** Avoid space between `iframe` and text.

Comment: So `padding-bottom: 56.25%;` seems to be the reason, as it looks fine with 100% height instead of 80%. Try to change this value.

Comment: Any chance to avoid `position:absolute;` or place the text inside the `div`, too?

Comment: @dsuess we can place text in `div` too.

Answer (score 0):

Add *negative* `margin-bottom` to the iframe wrapper, ie:

```
#videowrapper {
    margin-top: -80px;
}
```

and then tweak the margin to make it work for you

```css
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom: -80px;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-bottom: -80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoWrapper" id="tmp">
    <iframe id="crntplay" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/id?autoplay=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="afteriframe">some text here</p>
```

Comment: I guess it's difficult to _fix_ a distance issue with a *pixel value*, while all the containers are *relatives with percentage*. This may look fine in this small preview box, but not in real browser windows, which can have different width.

Comment: @joe_young I need responsive `iframe`. With this I didn't get it since `height:80%;`

Answer (score 0):

set [iframe height and width inline](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) and remove the rules from css.

```
<iframe width="200" height="200" id="crntplay" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/id?autoplay=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Inline attributes are more specefic than CSS-rules, they *overpower the css rules.* Nevertheless it's good practice to separate HTML markup and styling. That's what CSS was made for.

Answer (score 0):

When you have changed `height` of `iframe` you have also changed ratio of video. It is not 16:9 as it was before. You also have a `div` that contains an `iframe` which `padding-bottom` set to `56.25%` - and this was set in order to get the right ratio of video - 16:9. If you divide 9 by 16 you'll get 0,5625 then multiply it by 100% and you'll get your 56.25%. If you want to change the ratio of video by reducing it's height from 100% to 80% then multiply 0,5625 by 80 and you'll get 45. And now if you change `padding-bottom` of `.videoWrapper` to `45%` and set `height` of `iframe` back to `100%` you will see same ratio of video like in your question but you will see no space between video and text.

```css
.videoWrapper {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 45%; /* 16:9 */
 padding-top: 25px;
 height: 0;
 text-align:center;
 margin-bottom:1%;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoWrapper" id="tmp">
<iframe id="crntplay" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/id?autoplay=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
 some text here
```

But I see no point of changing video ratio at all